# Is it possible to use a small LCD to display load?

Tags: server, hardware

I'm putting together a super cheap rackmount server and it would be nice to have a little lcd in the 5.25" bay. I'm looking for the cheapest lcd that I can write out the cpu load to. Anyone done this already? Which product did you use and what software do I need to install to output this. If possible the output of the whole `uptime` command would be best.

Comment: Something like this product would suffice, but I'm not sure about linux compatability.... http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811996004&cm_re=lcd_5.25-_-11-996-004-_-Product

Comment: Linux compatibility info here:  http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Nmedia_pro-lcd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lcdproc` is the package you'd probably want to use. Installing is a lot more simple than the Myth wiki would have you believe:

```
sudo apt-get install lcdproc
```

It supports a whole load of drivers, a list of which can be seen on [its man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lcdd), along with instructions on how to configure the client software.

How you turn this list into real devices is something else. Some are direct brands, some are chipsets used by various products. Stick each into Google Shopping and see what you get. Most I can find appear to be around the £50 price point.

[This one](http://linitx.com/viewproduct.php?prodid=12439) is particularly pretty, supported... but £60.

Edit: There's also [`lcd4linux`](http://ssl.bulix.org/projects/lcd4linux/) which handles much the same stuff.

```
sudo apt-get install lcd4linux
```

Comment: Great. I'm looking forward to trying it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
"How you turn this list into real devices is something else"
```

This is a question best answered with the [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/), I might suspect.

And definitely under £50. But the "how to", I do not know. Would you please post here a link to a howto if you get it done? Thanks!

Comment: I have an Arduino actually and an H44780 driven LCD, so technically I could go that route, but I'm looking for something a little more plug-n-play. Here's a link to how to get the LCD working (I;ve tested it) http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/lcd.html and here's a way to talk to the Arduino serially (I've only done this with one character at a time, though) http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Python

Comment: Updated links: http://www.ladyada.net/learn/lcd/charlcd.html and http://drewish.com/content/2009/06/simple_arduino_serial_communications